# How to traverse multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list, traversal

I have two equal length lists. I want to traverse them both at the same time in order to perform some operation on each equivalently indexed item of each list.

It seems inefficient to create an index variable to iterate through the lists.

For example, this works:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
  print(a[i],b[i])
```

But can I do it without the index?

I did find: [Traversing multiple lists in django template in same for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132706/traversing-multiple-lists-in-django-template-in-same-for-loop) but it looks massively complicated for all I want to do and I have no idea what a django template is!

Comment: these all have their place - sometimes you need the index, sometimes just the items.  You can also get the items directly with zip: `for a_i, b_i in zip(a,b): ...`.  A word of caution that zip will truncate to the shortest list without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asking the question and searching some of the keywords I didn't understand, I came up with an example more simple than the one I found, equivalent to my examples above:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]

for j in zip(a,b):
  print(j[0],j[1])
```

This works because zip collates the two lists into a list of lists.

```
print(list(zip(a,b)))
>>> [(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
```

This is certainly a shortcut for coding, but I'm sure there must be an even more efficient way.

Comment: `for x,y in zip(a,b): print(x,y)`

Comment: I reckon not! More likely for x,y in zip(a,b): print(x,y)

Comment: Even so, there must be a truckload of processor overhead zipping the two lists together. I'm still searching for "efficient" rather than "lazy"! Maybe "efficient" is the opposite of "Python"?

Comment: I have no idea why you'd assume that this implementation would be any less efficient than any other just because it's so simple to do.

Comment: I expect `zip` to be very efficient. A [simple implementation of it is trivial](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/85791d4818d1bf30c9f405ad820c451e). There's nothing in there that has much overhead.

Comment: The [documented implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (although not necessarily the actual one) is a little more complicated, but seems to want to avoid exceptions, potentially for performance reasons, so it would be even better than mine if that's the reason.

Comment: I expect "efficient" depends on what you understand of the hardware. The first thing about the simple trivial implementation is that it starts by doubling up on your memory requirements. Not something contemporary coders consider. Then there's the fact that it iterates at all. If I have to manually iterate to build a new array in a different shape in order to iterate through it, then I may as well just iterate through it and do the job as I go. I think the topmost solution, although not at all pythonic is the most efficient from the machine perspective.

Comment: There shouldn't be any doubling of memory requirements. `iters` is a list of list iterators that are themselves quite small (they don't hold the values, they only pull them from the list when needed). The use of a generator function also means that only a single pair of elements (references to the original elements, not copies) are in memory at once unless the user puts them on a list.

Comment: Since the original data is int and the reference is likely to be at least a longword, it's more than doubling. (OK, only for this case. My real data type is a longish dict.)

Comment: How can a "question" be "opinion-based"? Honestly, if I'd not put an opinion in, they'd have moaned that I clearly didn't do any research.